# GStreamer "undefined reference to '__srget'"

Tags: android, gstreamer

I have troubles to run the GStreamer tutorials. I followed all tutorial steps, and run into an error.

**My System:**

- android-ndk-r11c, gstreamer-sdk-android-arm-debug-2013.6
- My System: Windows 10 - 64 bit

**The Error:**

```
C:\gstreamer-sdk-android-arm-debug-2013.6\share\gst-sdk\tutorials\android-tutorial-1>ndk-build
GStreamer      : [GEN] => gst-build/gstreamer_android.c
GStreamer      : [COMPILE] => gst-build/gstreamer_android.c
GStreamer      : [LINK] => gst-build/libgstreamer_android.so
lex.priv_gst_parse_yy.c:1598: error: undefined reference to '__srget'
gutils.c:2406: error: undefined reference to 'issetugid'
localcharset.c:158: error: undefined reference to '__srget'
localcharset.c:167: error: undefined reference to '__srget'
./localcharset.c:195: error: undefined reference to '__srget'
/home/slomo/Projects/android/android-ndk-r8e/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.7/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-androideabi/4.7/include-fixed/stdio.h:376: error: undefined reference to '__swbuf'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [buildsharedlibrary] Error 1

C:\gstreamer-sdk-android-arm-debug-2013.6\share\gst-sdk\tutorials\android-tutorial-1>
```

I tried:

> Windows linkage problems : Due to problems related to the standard linker, Google’s Gold Linker is used to build GStreamer applications.  Unfortunately, the Android NDK toolchain for Windows does not include the gold linker and the standard one has to be used.
>
> If you observe linkage problems, you can replace the linker in your Android NDK with the gold one from this project. Download the android-ndk-r8b-ma-windows.7z file, extract \android-ndk-r8b\toolchains\arm-linux-androideabi-4.6\prebuilt\windows\arm-linux-androideabi\bin\ld.exe (only this file is needed) and overwrite the one in the same folder in your Android NDK installation.

No effect. Any ideas how to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

I had similar problem before please give a try with ndk10b.It is always good to check in header files for **__srget** before move forward.

Comment: While this is an answer could you expand on it further? http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer

Comment: Gstreamer provides you binaries , so they might be built with older NDK version and they are verified possibly. First is to confirm NDK version is cause of problem we should grep for __srget in current NDK under use , if symbol doesn't exist then we are sure that ndk version is the problem. Going further you can download and try with older NDK.Even there is hint of being built with older ndk from error log android/android-ndk-r8e/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.7 as we can see ndk-r8e.